# How to use QSortFilterProxyModel's setFilterRegExp() along with filterAcceptsRow()

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt

While implementing `QSortFilterProxyModel` (to be used with `QTableView`) I have overridden the proxy's `filterAcceptsRow()` method by defining in it some custom logic (on how the items get filtered). Now it seems that overriding a proxy's "default" `filterAcceptsRow()`  conflicts with a build-in proxy's functionality built around `.setFilterRegExp()`

```
mySearchField=QLineEdit()
QObject.connect(mySearchField, SIGNAL("textChanged(QString)"), myProxyModel.setFilterRegExp)
```

While typing into `mySearchField` I do see that the proxy's `filterAcceptsRow()` is being constantly called . But since I have overrode its `filterAcceptsRow()` method with a custom logic no filtering on a text typed into the lineedit happens.

Question: Is it possible to keep both functionality: a simplicity of using proxy's built-in `.setFilterRegExp()` with custom defined `filterAcceptsRow()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `QSortFilterProxyModel`'s constructor a `self.searchText` variable is declared first:

```
class TaskProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TaskProxyModel, self).__init__()
        self.searchText=None
```

Defining a proxy's `setSearchText()` custom setter to be linked to `lineedit` (`lineedit` is used to enter a search keyword):

```
class MyProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyProxyModel, self).__init__()
        self.searchText=None

    def setSearchText(self, arg=None):
        self.searchText=arg
        self.reset()
```

Linking the `lineedit` to a proxy's `setSearchText()` setter-method:

```
myProxy=MyProxyModel()
lineEdit=QLineEdit()
lineEdit.textChanged.connect(myProxy.setSearchText)
```

At the beginning of proxy's `filterAcceptsRow()` checking if `self.searchText` is not None. 
If not then do some logic:

```
class MyProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyProxyModel, self).__init__()
        self.searchText=None

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, rowProc, parentProc):
        sourceModel=self.sourceModel()      
        indexProc=sourceModel.index(rowProc, 0, parentProc)
        node=sourceModel.data(indexProc, Qt.UserRole).toPyObject()

        if self.searchText:
            nodeName=node.getName()
            if nodeName and not str(self.searchText).lower() in nodeName.lower():
                return False
```